# How can I mask this CanvasRenderer?

Tags: unity, c#, geometry, masking

I'm creating a text box that allows for selectable text, based off of Unity's InputField. An issue I am now facing is that the selection highlight does not respond to masks (The parent has a mask, but it is just ignored) depth is also ignored, this seems to render through any other UI element that's in-front of it.:

[image]

I'm completely lost on how to go about masking it, so it does not show up past the bounds of the box. The code I used to generate it is heavily based off of Unity's, it's a bit long and kind of hacked together at the moment, I'm including it for references sake.

The method that generates the verts for the highlight in the .gif is `GenerateHighlight`

```
        private void UpdateGeometry()
    {
        if(caretCanvasRenderer == null && textBacker != null)
        {
            GameObject caret = new GameObject(transform.name + "Caret");
            caret.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
            caret.transform.SetParent(textBacker.transform);
            caret.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
            caret.layer = gameObject.layer;

            caretRectTransform = caret.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
            caretCanvasRenderer = caret.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
            caretCanvasRenderer.SetMaterial(Graphic.defaultGraphicMaterial, null);
            //caretCanvasRenderer.isMask = true;

            caret.AddComponent<LayoutElement>().ignoreLayout = true;

            AssignPositioningIfNeeded();
        }

        if (caretCanvasRenderer == null)
            return;

        OnFillVBO(VBO);

        if (VBO.Count == 0)
            caretCanvasRenderer.SetVertices(null, 0);
        else
            caretCanvasRenderer.SetVertices(VBO.ToArray(), VBO.Count);

        VBO.Clear();
    }

    private void OnFillVBO(List<UIVertex> vbo)
    {
        //if (!isFocused)
        //    return;

        Rect inputRect = textBacker.rectTransform.rect;
        Vector2 extents = inputRect.size;

        // get the text alignment anchor point for the text in local space
        Vector2 textAnchorPivot = Text.GetTextAnchorPivot(textBacker.alignment);
        Vector2 refPoint = Vector2.zero;
        refPoint.x = Mathf.Lerp(inputRect.xMin, inputRect.xMax, textAnchorPivot.x);
        refPoint.y = Mathf.Lerp(inputRect.yMin, inputRect.yMax, textAnchorPivot.y);

        // Ajust the anchor point in screen space
        Vector2 roundedRefPoint = textBacker.PixelAdjustPoint(refPoint);

        // Determine fraction of pixel to offset text mesh.
        // This is the rounding in screen space, plus the fraction of a pixel the text anchor pivot is from the corner of the text mesh.
        Vector2 roundingOffset = roundedRefPoint - refPoint + Vector2.Scale(extents, textAnchorPivot);
        roundingOffset.x = roundingOffset.x - Mathf.Floor(0.5f + roundingOffset.x);
        roundingOffset.y = roundingOffset.y - Mathf.Floor(0.5f + roundingOffset.y);

        if (!hasSelection)
            GenerateCursor(vbo, roundingOffset);
        else
            GenerateHightlight(vbo, roundingOffset);
    }

    private void GenerateCursor(List<UIVertex> vbo, Vector2 roundingOffset)
    {
        if (!caretVisible)
            return;
        if(cursorVerts == null)
            CreateCursorVerts();

        float width = 1f;
        float height = textBacker.fontSize;
        int adjustedPosition = Mathf.Max(0, caretPositionInternal - drawStart);
        TextGenerator generator = textBacker.cachedTextGenerator;

        if(generator == null)
            return;

        if (textBacker.resizeTextForBestFit)
            height = generator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit / textBacker.pixelsPerUnit;

        Vector2 startPosition = Vector2.zero;

        // Calculate startPosition
        if (generator.characterCountVisible + 1 > adjustedPosition || adjustedPosition == 0)
        {
            UICharInfo cursorChar = generator.characters[adjustedPosition];
            startPosition.x = cursorChar.cursorPos.x;
            startPosition.y = cursorChar.cursorPos.y;
        }
        startPosition.x /= textBacker.pixelsPerUnit;

        // TODO: Only clamp when Text uses horizontal word wrap.
        if (startPosition.x > textBacker.rectTransform.rect.xMax)
            startPosition.x = textBacker.rectTransform.rect.xMax;

        cursorVerts[0].position = new Vector3(startPosition.x, startPosition.y - height, 0.0f);
        cursorVerts[1].position = new Vector3(startPosition.x + width, startPosition.y - height, 0.0f);
        cursorVerts[2].position = new Vector3(startPosition.x + width, startPosition.y, 0.0f);
        cursorVerts[3].position = new Vector3(startPosition.x, startPosition.y, 0.0f);

        if (roundingOffset != Vector2.zero)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursorVerts.Length; i++)
            {
                UIVertex uiv = cursorVerts[i];
                uiv.position.x += roundingOffset.x;
                uiv.position.y += roundingOffset.y;
                vbo.Add(uiv);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursorVerts.Length; i++)
            {
                vbo.Add(cursorVerts[i]);
            }
        }

        startPosition.y = Screen.height - startPosition.y;
        Input.compositionCursorPos = startPosition;
    }

    private void GenerateHightlight(List<UIVertex> vbo, Vector2 roundingOffset)
    {
        int startChar = Mathf.Max(0, caretPositionInternal - drawStart);
        int endChar = Mathf.Max(0, caretSelectPositionInternal - drawStart);

        // Ensure pos is always less then selPos to make the code simpler
        if (startChar > endChar)
        {
            int temp = startChar;
            startChar = endChar;
            endChar = temp;
        }

        endChar -= 1;
        TextGenerator generator = textBacker.cachedTextGenerator;

        int currentLineIndex = DetermineCharacterLine(startChar, generator);
        float height = textBacker.fontSize;

        if (textBacker.resizeTextForBestFit)
            height = generator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit / textBacker.pixelsPerUnit;

        if (generator != null && generator.lines.Count > 0)
        {
            // TODO: deal with multiple lines with different line heights.
            height = generator.lines[0].height;
        }

        if (textBacker.resizeTextForBestFit && generator != null)
        {
            height = generator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit;
        }

        int nextLineStartIdx = GetLineEndPosition(generator, currentLineIndex);

        UIVertex vert = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vert.uv0 = Vector2.zero;
        vert.color = selectionColor;

        int currentChar = startChar;
        while (currentChar <= endChar && currentChar < generator.characterCountVisible)
        {
            if (currentChar + 1 == nextLineStartIdx || currentChar == endChar)
            {
                UICharInfo startCharInfo = generator.characters[startChar];
                UICharInfo endCharInfo = generator.characters[currentChar];
                Vector2 startPosition = new Vector2(startCharInfo.cursorPos.x / textBacker.pixelsPerUnit, startCharInfo.cursorPos.y);
                Vector2 endPosition = new Vector2((endCharInfo.cursorPos.x + endCharInfo.charWidth) / textBacker.pixelsPerUnit, startPosition.y - height / textBacker.pixelsPerUnit);

                // Checking xMin as well due to text generator not setting possition if char is not rendered.
                if (endPosition.x > textBacker.rectTransform.rect.xMax || endPosition.x < textBacker.rectTransform.rect.xMin)
                    endPosition.x = textBacker.rectTransform.rect.xMax;

                vert.position = new Vector3(startPosition.x, endPosition.y, 0.0f) + (Vector3)roundingOffset;
                vbo.Add(vert);

                vert.position = new Vector3(endPosition.x, endPosition.y, 0.0f) + (Vector3)roundingOffset;
                vbo.Add(vert);

                vert.position = new Vector3(endPosition.x, startPosition.y, 0.0f) + (Vector3)roundingOffset;
                vbo.Add(vert);

                vert.position = new Vector3(startPosition.x, startPosition.y, 0.0f) + (Vector3)roundingOffset;
                vbo.Add(vert);

                startChar = currentChar + 1;
                currentLineIndex++;

                nextLineStartIdx = GetLineEndPosition(generator, currentLineIndex);
            }
            currentChar++;
        }
    }
```

**The gist of it**, is it creates a new gameobject. Adds a canvas renderer, and rect transform. Calls the appropriate method that generates the vertices, and then assigns those to the `CanvasRenderer.

Comment: Had the exact same problem trying to implement selection based on the TextMeshPro Label :). Solution mentioned below worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [UI.Graphic](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) and [UI.MaskableGraphic](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.MaskableGraphic.html)

You'll want to write a class that derives from [MaskableGraphic] then implement the methods to fill the VBO when the UI asks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the new Input Caret `GameObject` created by the `InputField` and masking should work.

```
class Masker : MaskableGraphic
{
}
```